# Trouble loading .png file using LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

It will load files `badlogic.jpg` and `icon.png` but it won't load `start` or `stop.png` files, yet they are in same folder.

Using Android Studio

[image]

Comment: So when calling `new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/badlogic.jpg"))` inside your constructor it works? Or did you call it somewhere else?

Comment: in same place, just switching names it works instead for example 
"start.png" i put "icon.png" it works

Comment: Are you using an 8bit or 16bit encoded start.png image? you can only use 8bit encoded images as 16bit won't work.

Comment: i used 16 bit, thx a lot

Comment: Let me know if that was the issue and I'll add an answer if needed.

Comment: yes that was the issue

Answer (score 5):

LibGdX uses `stb_image` for image loading.

`no 16-bit-per-channel PNG` is one of the limitation of `std_image` so you 
need to use 8 bit `.png` image.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/jni/gdx2d/stb_image.h#L24

You may check your image by [ImageMagick](https://imageoptim.com/mac). You can also use [pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) for the same.